# Profile edit : check the modify all and uncheck the delete checkbox

Tags: administration, profile

I need to give access to user of a certain profile to modify all the cases. But I also need that theses users can't delete theses case. For that I try to edit the profile by checkinf the "modify all" and unchecking the "delete" checkbox. But When I uncheck the the "delete" the "modify all" is automatically unchecked too.

I need to know if there is another way to do that ? Can I give the access to modify all the cases to a profile and prevent them from deleting the cases ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ModifyAll"  Permission is supreme permission. Its like user view, edit and delete all records ***regardless of sharing***.

- For your understanding: You uncheck all the permissions and Check
  "Modifyall" permission.

  What  You have observed?

  ***Its automatically checks all other permission(CRUD).***

My suggestion is you can better to handle your "delete" scenario using custom buttons logic or triggers.

Comment: Ok I understand. So I really need that they can't delete the cases. I see somewhere that there is the possibility to create a sharing rule (if I uncheck the modify all and uncheck the delete) that would permit the profile to see / modify all the cases (even the ones they don't own) but I don't know if this is the right way to do that... and if I can make a sharing rule for profiles

Comment: Profile level permissions are different and record sharing is different.

Comment: Ok, so I don't really understand how I can handle that... See an modify all cases but not delete them

Comment: why cant use trigger. In your trigger you can check certian profile is trying to delete it .you can throw error

Comment: check this post:https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i7C5AAI

Comment: So make a trigger before delete on case, if the profile is the one I'm managing I display an error ?